# Angular js http post always executing successcallback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post

I am trying to post something using http post and was referring to their official documentation and used the same example from the official documentation. However whenever there is an error then it should go the errorCallback callback function as expected but it doesn't and I am dying to figure out why. Am I missing something here? I have tried both the success and error scenarios and even used the short hand and full versions of http post. Please find my code below.

```
var url = 'posturl', data = 'parameters', config = 'contenttype';
        $http.post(url, data, config).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("Failure"+response);
        });


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

One of the weirdest parts is to find that it is working in code pen and here is the link below
https://codepen.io/webdesigning/pen/oBEaqx

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is my first post so please be Nice!

Comment: Looks fine to me. Can you check the API you are consuming?

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: It is a generic error. but it is not about the error. It is about why it is always executing the successcallback. But anyway Do you want me to still post the error?.